# How do I change the name of a solana collection prior to minting?

Tags: solana, candy-machine

[The MCC standard names a collection "collection NFT by default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEHGk.png)

Following metaplex's new MCC standard, naming a collection is not as simple as putting the collection name in the NFT's metadata anymore. Instead, the new standard migrates the NFT details on-chain.

The tool that metaplex provides (https://collections.metaplex.com/) can rename a collection but it can only do so once the NFT is minted. This brings me back to my main question: How do I change the name of a solana collection prior to minting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something you need to know regarding MCC. When you run `upload` command a NFT without metadata will be minted to the wallet that you provide as authority (`-k` parameter), this empty NFT is the default collection NFT and will act as portrait of all the unminted NFTs inside ur collection. The reason that you see `Collection NFT` as portrait is because that NFT has no metadata. Also all unminted NFTs are attached to this collection unless you use `set_collection` given as `-m` parameter a new collection id (another created collection NFT), but this can only be done if your CandyMachine has 0 minted items.

In order to solve the Collection NFT you just have to add metadata to the minted default collection NFT. If you are on mainnet-beta I recommend you to use [this website](https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io), you can also use [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/update.html) (ut you will have to upload ur metadata to an storage before).

You can see what is the collection NFT that is attached to ur CandyMachine using the [show command](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/update#show-settings) that will output the following info about the collection NFT (and more info about the CM): `Collection mint:  Gfe...6q9`, that `Collection mint` is the NFT that is attached to ur CM as collection if its metadata is empty you just have to update it so every minted NFT will be attached to a non-empty NFT as collection.

Comment: But how can i specify collection metadata with metaboss? I have to provide a file like the config file provided for the candymachine? And which are its parameters?